# Unable to fetch response from file_get_contents using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, file-get-contents

Gurus,

I am trying to fetch tracking details using the austpost.com.au website for which I have written the below code however, it doesn't seem to fetch anything.

```
$austpost_url = 'https://digitalapi.auspost.com.au/shipmentsgatewayapi/watchlist/shipments/99702032243801004670904';

$options = array(
        'method'  => 'get',
        'contentType' => 'application/json',
        'muteHttpExceptions' => true,
        'headers'  => array ('Accept' => 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                              'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
                              'AP_CHANNEL_NAME' => 'WEB_DETAIL',
                              'api-key' => 'd11f9456-11c3-456d-9f6d-f7449cb9af8e',
                              'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
                              'Origin' => 'https://auspost.com.au',
                              'Referer' => 'https://auspost.com.au/mypost/track/'),
    );

$context  = stream_context_create($options);

$html = file_get_contents($austpost_url, false, $context);

echo $html;
```

Direct Tracking Link: https://auspost.com.au/mypost/track/#/details/99702032243801004670904

I found this by going to the NETWORK tab in Chrome and figured out which request is loading the tracking details. Basically I am just after getting the **status of the shipment**. Snapshot below:
[image]

Any help in this would be much appreciated as I am using PHP to drive my code where I want to update the WordPress posts statuses based on the shipment status (that I can handle) however, stuck here on how I can get this shipment status before I move on.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you need a valid recaptcha token and proof that you are not a robot. Won't be that simple, as you think. The easiest, but paid method, would be to use some captcha solving companies, like https://2captcha.com (not a sponsor of that answer) and their `PHP` libs.

If you want to use their api, you need to auth with username and password via basic auth. More details in here: https://developers.auspost.com.au/apis/shipping-and-tracking/reference/track-items

Comment: Thanks. I already know about their API but I dont have their eParcel account hence I cant access it as they have rejected my request. They only eParcel accounts if we have 2000+ parcels per year.

Answer (score 0):

First check the fopen is on or off , add the phpinfo(); code in main file and check this .

Otherwise use the Curl function instead of file_get_contents();

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. I haven’t used Curl function before, can you tell me how do I pass these arguments in that? Thanks